# Angular code doesn't delete json by passing id to JAVA (with Spring)

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring, angular-resource

My application should **delete** one Session object by using ID, that I pass from Angular to Java class by using Spring mapping. It doesn't quite work. Nothing happens if done from UI. I checked the logs in browser: no errors. Then i check the logs in Java and it appears that angular didn't reach Java.

If I use from browser address bar: rest/session/delete/**IDNUMBEROFSESSION**, then it works and deletes the data (although after returns HTTP Status 404 -). Can anybody please suggest what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much!!!

SessionResource.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/session")
public class SessionResource {

  private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionResource.class);

  @Autowired
  private SessionService sessionService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Session> get(@PathVariable String id) {
    Session session = sessionService.findById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<Session>(session, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
  }

  // DELETE
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/delete/{id}")
  public void delete(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    System.out.println("Starting to enter request mapping delete and calling sessionService.delete function");
    Session session = sessionService.findById(id);
    sessionService.delete(session);
  }
}
```

Resource.JS with this code:

```
app.factory('SessionResource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('rest/session/:sessionId',
        {
            speakerId: '@sessionId'
        },
        {
            'update': { method: 'PUT' },
            'delete': { method: 'GET' ,  isArray: true}
        });
});
```

Comment: how you are calling `SessionResource` delete method from controller?

Comment: Hello, like this: this.delete = function (data, callback) {

        if (data.id) {

            var withDelete = "delete/" + data.id;

            withDelete = SessionResource.delete(withDelete, function () {
                callback();
            });
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call delete method of `SessionResource` by passing `sessionId` parameter to it.

```
SessionResource.delete({sessionId: data.id}, function(response){
   callback(response);
})
```

Comment: This generated an error: Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `delete`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object (Request: GET rest/session/566c2f95a826c933bf35b1da)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$resource/badcfg?p0=delete&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=rest%2Fsession%2F566c2f95a826c933bf35b1da

Comment: Then i changed data.id to withDelete and it gives me this error: GET http://localhost:9000/rest/session/delete%2F566c2f95a826c933bf35b1da 400 (Bad Request) Thank you for your help and time!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I solved it by changing the structure of  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/delete{id}") I know it is not good, but I was in a big hurry! Thank you.